# Git certificate validation error, but openssl succeeds

Tags: certificates

```
$ git clone https://stash.z-hub.io/scm/zp/z-push.git
Cloning into 'z-push'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://stash.z-hub.io/scm/zp/z-push.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

but

```
$ openssl s_client -connect stash.z-hub.io:443 -CAfile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt | grep -i verify
depth=2 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL Wildcard, CN = *.z-hub.io
verify return:1
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

How can CA trust be different?

Answer (score 0):

With openssl you are using a specific port (443). Maybe it is the git default port that is not trusted by the ca-certificates. I think git by default uses port 9418.

Try doing this:

```
git clone https://stash.z-hub.io:443/scm/zp/z-push.git
```

Comment: Nope, that's not it.
fatal: unable to access 'https://stash.z-hub.io:443/scm/zp/z-push.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none